# Getting YL-69 Moisture sensor to work and display analogue input

Tags: sensor

I'm new to the raspberry pi and after getting a simple temperature sensor to work bought a YL-69 (comes with YL-38 too) but can't get any analogue data from it.

http://www.tiagoespinha.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2014-05-09-12.51.20.jpg are the two sensors I have currently.

My current setup is:

YL-69 and YL-38 connected via the 2 pin side.

YL-69:VCC goes to the Rasp 3.3v power pin 1.

YL-69:GND goes to the ground pin on Rasp.

YL-69:AO goes to one of my GPIO pins(3).

I'm using the pigpio python library but pi.read(gpio) just gives me a reading of 1.

What do I need to do to get this to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi does not have any analog inputs, you will neeed to add an ADC and connect your sensors to the ADC. Adafruit has a nice tutorial using the [MCP3008](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/overview). Tutsplus has a [tutorial](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-raspberry-pi-moisture-sensor-to-monitor-your-plants--mac-52875) using the MCP3008 with a moisture sensor.

Comment: Can any ADC be used? I've just noticed I have a ADC0832 in a kit I bought. I'm happy to dig a little deeper on how to get it to work, but you might be able to save me a bit of time if it's not compatible. Thanks!

Comment: I have not tried so can't say unequivocally  it but a quick google search appears to indicate that it will work. https://www.google.com/search?q=ADC0832&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS497US497&oq=ADC0832&aqs=chrome..69i57.1357303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=ADC0832+raspberry+pi

Comment: The first link http://heinrichhartmann.com/2014/12/14/Sensor-Monitoring-with-RaspberryPi-and-Circonus.html looks promising.

Comment: That tutorial seems to use up 4 GPIO pins, is that normal just to get an Analog output?!

Comment: @john If I remember correctly the ADC0832 is a spi chip so it is going to require a clock, mosi, miso and a slave select so this is normal. For reference you may want to read this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus

Comment: If you do choose to go down the MCP3008 route, I recommend Matt Hawkins' tutorial here: http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/